# How to handle c enum callback function in Swift

Tags: c, swift, callback

I want to set a custom swift callback function like so

```
codecCtx.get_format = negotiatePixelFormat
```

where the C callback function `get_format` is declared as this

```
var get_format: (@convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<AVCodecContext>?, UnsafePointer<AVPixelFormat>?) -> AVPixelFormat)!
```

and my custom swift function function looks like this

```
private func negotiatePixelFormat(codecContext:AVCodecContext,pixelFormat:AVPixelFormat)->AVPixelFormat{
        while pixelFormat == AV_PIX_FMT_NONE {
            if pixelFormat == AV_PIX_FMT_VIDEOTOOLBOX{
                if codecContext.hwaccel_context == nil{
                    return codecContext.pix_fmt //TBD
                }
            }
            return pixelFormat //TBD
        }
        return AV_PIX_FMT_NONE //TBD
    }
```

But I have no idea how to merge these types of functions together neither where I can search for some kind of documentation.

---

The **original all C code** is the following

```
codecCtx->get_format = negotiatePixelFormat
```

where the custom callback function is this

```
static enum AVPixelFormat negotiate_pixel_format(struct AVCodecContext *s, const enum AVPixelFormat *fmt) {
    while (*fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_NONE) {
        if (*fmt == AV_PIX_FMT_VIDEOTOOLBOX) {  
            if (s->hwaccel_context == NULL) {
                int result = av_videotoolbox_default_init(s);
                if (result < 0) {
                    return s->pix_fmt;
                }
            }
            return *fmt;
        }
        ++fmt;
    }
    return s->pix_fmt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you know that the type of the callback is imported as:

```
var get_format: (@convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<AVCodecContext>?, UnsafePointer<AVPixelFormat>?) -> AVPixelFormat)!
```

you need to define a function taking `(UnsafeMutablePointer<AVCodecContext>?, UnsafePointer<AVPixelFormat>?)`, and returning `AVPixelFormat`.

So, you may need to declare a Swift function such as:

```
func negotiatePixelFormat(_ s: UnsafeMutablePointer<AVCodecContext>?, _ fmt: UnsafePointer<AVPixelFormat>?) -> AVPixelFormat {
    //...
}
```

---

As far as I can see, your callback function in C would look like as follows in Swift:

```
func negotiatePixelFormat(_ s: UnsafeMutablePointer<AVCodecContext>?, _ fmt: UnsafePointer<AVPixelFormat>?) -> AVPixelFormat {
    guard let s = s, var fmt = fmt else {
        return AV_PIX_FMT_NONE
    }
    while fmt.pointee != AV_PIX_FMT_NONE {
        if fmt.pointee == AV_PIX_FMT_VIDEOTOOLBOX {
            if s.pointee.hwaccel_context == nil {
                let result = av_videotoolbox_default_init(s)
                if result < 0 {
                    return s.pointee.pix_fmt
                }
            }
            return fmt.pointee
        }
        fmt += 1
    }
    return s.pointee.pix_fmt
}
```

Your info shown lacks some details so you may need to fix some parts of this code.

Comment: This is looking good so far, but now I get the error "A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func' or a literal closure" Edit: Declared it as a global function, now the error is away.